# Responding to events in a SignalR hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, events, event-handling, signalr

I'm looking for a way to first expose an event in my repository class,
and register to that event in my signalr hub,
for example if a user was added to my application all the connected users will get notified.
I'm using asp.net Mvc in my backend.
What is the recommended approach for doing so,
where should I start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to notify other clients it's as simple as executing a message on all connected clients.

AKA:

```
class MyHub : Hub 
{
    public void AddUserToApplication()
    {
        ...Your logic to add your user...
        Clients.All.newUserInApp(); // newUserInApp would then have to be defined on the client.
    }
}
```

If you then want to perform this type of behavior outside of your hub, aka maybe in a timer you can access the hubs "Clients" property via:

```
IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
```

So you can then do:

```
context.Clients.All.newUserInApp();
```

Comment: First, thank you, but I've meant to expose an event in my repository for example, "public event MyAppEvent UserAdded;" and in my hub to do something like "repository.UserAdded += MyCustomFunctionName" and set that function IN the hub itself.

Comment: You can do that with a static hub method, within the static hub method you'll have to use my second approach at retrieving the hubs context.